# 1:1 Video Chat that doesn't require logins

Tags: chat, video-conferencing

I'm looking for a video chat system that supports 1 on 1 chats and **does not** require any logins.

Currently we use Google Hangouts or Skype for interviews, but we can't always assume the candidate will have a Google account or have Skype installed. Yes we can always make people download and/or create accounts prior to the interview, but we'd like something that doesn't take any work on the interviewees end.

Are there any web services that support this? Any APIs available that we can build a simple web portal around? Paid is ok, but free is preferred.

Also, no fancy features needed. We just need two people to be able to see and talk to each other. I.E., no need for text chat, file sharing, etc.

Comment: Maybe WebRTC, which gets [recommended in this answer](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/799/60) on my question [Free/Libre voice & video chat alternative to Skype?](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/243/60)

Answer (score 4):

*Unfortunately, as of 2019 AwesomeTalk [has officially shut down.](https://web.archive.org/web/20160306044128/http://www.awesometalk.com/)*

---

[AwesomeTalk](https://www.awesometalk.com/) does this. From my experience with it, it works very well, the video and audio quality is clear and I've noticed little to no stuttering or lag. It's just as you ask, nothing fancy, just straight 1 to 1 video chat. Works on all major browsers and even has a chrome extension.

- Free
- No login/signup
- Disposable private urls

Answer (score 3):

You may try Cisco Webex Meeting. You can invite anybody and you can send the meeting invite to their email id. No logins, no signup for the candidates.

You can do screen-sharing, control-desktop, video chat, join the audio conference via computer, dial in via phone or get a call from Webex.

PS :

1. There is free version where up to to 3 people can join, you need to explore the possibility of the video chat in the free version.
2. Citrix GotoMeeting is also an similar alternative

Answer (score 2):

[Jitsi Meet](https://jitsi.org/jitsi-meet/) is [open source](https://github.com/jitsi), does not require any account and you can self-host it if you want. It works in the browser, so no installation needed.

> Jitsi Meet - Secure, Simple and Scalable Video Conferences that you use as a standalone app or embed in your web application.

You can try it on https://meet.jit.si/. There are other instances as well, you'll find them with an common internet search.

[image: Screenshot of the Jisti Meet landing page]

Comment: Public instance (meet.jit.si) started  requiring an account recently.

Answer (score 1):

You can look at [SignalRTC](http://signalrtc.com/), it's a video chat web application (no need to install anyting, no browser plugins), which uses WebRTC and SignalR, works only on Chrome and Firefox, not IE. I didn't check other browser.

No registration, user can enter any name.

**Disclaimer:** I'm developer of this web app and now it's in development process, probably alpha version.

Answer (score 1):

The recent [Skype announcement](https://www.skype.com/en/free-conference-call/) may be helpful in your case:

```
Easy video meetings with no sign ups or downloads:

1. Generate link
2. Share
3. Join call
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Zoom](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoom_Video_Communications):

- supports 1 on 1 chats (the admin of the meeting can require a password to access the meeting)
- does not require any logins
- has text chat
- has screen sharing
- free tier: the Zoom Basic (free) plan has a 40-minute time limit on meetings with 3 or more participants.

FYI: [Zoom has been criticized for its data collection practices](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Zoom_Video_Communications&oldid=949274808#Criticism).

Answer (score 0):

*Note: As of April 2020, this answer is no longer valid.*

*The appear.in website now states: "Due to trademark infringement of our property, the video conferencing previously offered on this site is no longer available."*

*appear.in [was possibly renamed to Whereby](https://www.blendy.co/en/our-blog/the-video-conferencing-tool-appear-in-becomes-whereby/), at https://whereby.com/ . That site offers video chat, but requires a login to use.*

---

I would use **[appear.in](https://appear.in/)**

Video conversations with up to 8 people in your browser - no downloads, no login. Just name your channel and you are on. Works in all modern browsers, even mobile.

[image: appear.in User Interface]

Answer (score 0):

Talky ( https://talky.io ) should meet your needs.

- No login required, just append a random name to the URL to create a chat (such as https://talky.io/MyFancyName )
- Based on WebRTC, so works in any modern browser, on both desktop and mobile.
- Offers audio and video, text chat, and screen sharing
- By default, anyone with the URL can enter a chat. If desired, a chat can be protected by setting a password.
- Allows up to six people per chat.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [BlueJeans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BlueJeans_Network):

- supports 1 on 1 chats (the admin of the meeting can prevent people from joining the meeting)
- does not require any logins
- has text chat
- has screen sharing
- does not have file sharing