# Video chat alternative to Skype on Windows/Linux

Tags: cross-platform, video-conferencing

Is there any video chat app that works on Windows and Linux and **has an always-on-top / pop out video window** like Skype?

Bonus points if it's open-source and/or allows self-hosting.

Comment: See also: [*Free/Libre voice & video chat alternative to Skype?*](http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/243/60)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try [Ekiga](http://www.ekiga.org). It's an **open-source** SoftPhone, **video conferencing** and instant messenger software. It runs on windows and linux. I believe you can **host** with it, but I've never done it. It should be explained in the [Manual](http://wiki.ekiga.org/index.php/Manual). 
To make it **always on top** with windows, I use [AutoHotkey](https://www.autohotkey.com/?mobile). There are some good explanations in [this HowToGeek article](http://www.howtogeek.com/196958/the-3-best-ways-to-make-a-window-always-on-top-on-windows/).

Answer (score 2):

[Jitsi meet](http://meet.jitsi.org). You can always make the browser window on top. It is open source.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, [TrueConf](http://trueconf.com/) allows self-hosting. It is not open-source. They have a separate server and clients for many platforms including Linux. I remember TrueConf company as an experts in video conferencing. I met their representatives on one exhibit.

Answer (score 1):

Try [Google Hangouts](http://hangouts.google.com).

Download it as Application **OR** Use it as extension in the browser(Only in Chrome)

Comment: Please post a screenshot showing its always-on-top / pop out video window, which is a requirement.